# How do I stop a field from inheriting ng-touched class from its parent element

Tags: html, css, angular

Im trying to build a form in angular, when you blur on a field and the field is in an invalid state it adds a 2px red border around the edges of the field, the problem is that when one input field is touched all of them inherit the touched because the ngform object applies the ng-touched class to the form element which in turn all inputs inherit. what is the correct way of doing what I'm looking for?

[Picture of what I think the issue is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ia9zJ.png)
[Only one of these should be highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiSSb.png)
[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwFEY.png)
[CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcYCN.png)

Answer (score 0):

if you want use ngModel alone use a template reference variable

```
#myTemplateVar="ngModel"
```

Else, if you want to make a binding use [(ngModel)], see [Angular docs template driven form](https://angular.io/guide/forms#template-driven-forms)

And, please, better write the code, not use images, if you write the code, select it and use Ctrl+K it's is formated as code

Comment: can I get some clarification, I am using a template varable the problem lies with the fact that all input elements are nested within the form tag which in turn automatically is applied ngForm directive which in turn applies the ng-touched class to all elements within the form, so when i touch one input field, it applies ng-touched class to all input fields by inheritence, how do i stop this?

Comment: I make a stackblitz, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i4ccrf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html. The diference is that you has an error in `<div class=form-`, you need use quotes, and I dont' understand your .css `.form-control.ng-touched.ng-invalid`, for me is only `.ng-touched-ng-invalid`